# Ifttt skip function if device triggered within last hour

Tags: javascript, ifttt

So what i am trying to do is implement some filter code in an ifttt applet that will skip the action if it was already performed within the last hour

Its for triggering my heating which is a dumb system with a switchbot button pusher
How I want it to work is for an alexa phrase to trigger the push of the button, but if that already happened within the last hour I was wondering is it possible to skip the action under that condition

Comment: You should probably ask this on [iot stack exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ifttt)

Comment: And I can see you've already asked it on reddit